# Replacing characters in a string in Python

Tags: python, string, replace, cryptography, character

Working on a simple (very simple, laughably weak) cryptography program for an assignment, and I seem to be running into the same error no matter which way I go about it.

```
 def cryptofied(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
            text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text
```

EDIT: now using
     def cryptofied(text, dic):
        ret = ""
        for p in range(len(text)):
                ret += dic[text[p]]
        return ret

And

```
def encode(codedMsg):
    print(codedMsg, '   Here was your message to be encoded.')
    lock = {'A':'X', 'B':'P', 'C':'M', 'D':'G', 'E':'T', 'F':'D', 'G':'H', 'H':'L', 'I':'Y', 'J':'O', 'K':'N', 'L':'Z', 'M':'B', 'N':'W', 'O':'E', 'P':'A', 'Q':'R', 'R':'K', 'S':'J', 'T':'U', 'U':'F', 'V':'S', 'W':'C', 'X':'I', 'Y':'Q', 'Z':'V'}
    codedMsgTest = cryptofied(codedMsg, lock)
    print(codedMsgTest, 'here is your coded message')
```

However, when I input, for example, "frank" as the codedMsg, it will spit back at "GKXCC", which is obviously incorrect.  From what I can tell, the problem is that it is changing the "K" to an "N", and then changing both instances of "N" into "C".  What can I do to eliminate this?

EDIT:
So, problem with this code now is that if a character is used that is not in my lock, an error comes back.  How can I ignore these characters?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for an excellent question - not many new users write questions as good as this one. Great to have you here, and I hope you'll enjoy contributing to this site in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over the word with indices and then modify them one after the other as shown below:

```
for i in xrange(len(text)):
    text[i] = dic[text[i]]
```

but [there is a method called `maketrans()`, which allows you to do exactly this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans).

```
import string
s1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
s2 = "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
trans = string.maketrans(s1,s2)
strtrans = "THIS IS A SAMPLE PROGRAM FOR MAKETRANS"
outstr = strtrans.translate(trans)
print outstr      # ULYJ YJ X JXBAZT AKEHKXB DEK BXNTUKXWJ
```

Comment: Use ```s1 = "".join(lock.keys())``` and ```s2 = "".join([lock[l] for l in s1])``` to make the strings from the ```lock``` dict

Comment: I really like this answer, and I would say it is probably the quickest to input, but since I've already done the work for the other, I think that Pavel's suggestion is probably the most useful for this instance

Answer (score 2):

this is because `text.replace(i, j)` operates on *all* matches of `i`.

instead of iterating over the dictionary

```
for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
```

you need to iterate over the positions in the input word

```
ret = ""
for p in range(len(text)):
        ret += dic[text[p]]
return ret
```

Comment: Now, ```ret += dic[text[p]]``` needs to be ```ret += dic[text[p].upper()]``` since only upper case letters are in ```dic```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the string itself:

```
>>> lock = {'A':'X', 'B':'P', 'C':'M', 'D':'G', 'E':'T', 'F':'D', 'G':'H', 'H':'L', 'I':'Y', 'J':'O', 'K':'N', 'L':'Z', 'M':'B', 'N':'W', 'O':'E', 'P':'A', 'Q':'R', 'R':'K', 'S':'J', 'T':'U', 'U':'F', 'V':'S', 'W':'C', 'X':'I', 'Y':'Q', 'Z':'V'}
>>> text = "FRANK"
>>> encrypted_text = ""
>>> for char in text:
...     encrypted_text += lock.get(char)
... 
>>> encrypted_text
'DKXWN'
>>>
```